# How do I get the value inside a value in JSON with VB.NET

Tags: json, vb.net, treeview, nodes

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and coding in Visual Basic. 
I have a JSON file and I read through it and I can get the name and value of an item.
What I cannot get is the name and value of an item inside the value of another item.
I can get "Page-1.htm" and everything in the braces for "Page-1.htm", but I cannot get just "title" or just "Safety". 
I know I can get "Safety" if I know "title" is there by item("title").Value, but as you can see some items will have only title and some have numbers so I cannot get the info out that way.

Here is the JSON

```
{
    "Page-1.htm":{
        "title":  "Safety",
        "001":    "1. Purpose",
        "002":    "2. Definitions"
    },
    "Page-2.htm":{
        "title":  "Testing",
        "001":    "Test first",
        "002":    "Test Again",
        "003":    "Final Test"
    },
    "Page-3.htm":{
         "title":  "Once Again"
    }
}
```

Here is the start of my VB

```
Try
    Dim reader = New StreamReader(jsonFile.ToString())
    Dim rawresp As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
    Dim jResults As JObject = JObject.Parse(rawresp)
    Dim results As List(Of JToken) = jResults.Children().ToList()

    For Each item As JProperty in results
        'This works and gives me nodes in my TreeView
        Dim rootName As String = item.Name
        Dim root As TreeNode = tvContent.Nodes.Add(rootName)
        'This does not work to add child nodes because I can't get the info I need
        '"inside value" would be "Safety" or "1. Purpose", or "2. etc" from the JSON
        DIm childNode as TreeNode = tvContent.Nodes(0).Nodes.Add("inside value")
    Next

Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
For Each child In item.Children
    For Each value In child.Values
        root.Nodes.Add(value.ToString)
    Next
Next
```

To get both, name and value, you need to look at the `JProperties`.

```
For Each child In item.Children
    For Each jProp As JProperty In child
        root.Nodes.Add(String.Format("{0} = {1}", jProp.Name, jProp.Value))
        'or simply
        'root.Nodes.Add(jProp.ToString)
    Next
Next
```

Comment: I went ahead and marked this as an answer. I was able to get the inner values out.  Thank you much.  But Is there a way to get back the other  inner info too?  The "title" or "001", "002" parts?  Because I am dynamically creating the Tags for the items and using those to complete a link.  So first I get the item.Name which is the Page-1.htm and then I would need to add the "001" to the end of that with a # in the middle (Page-1.htm#001) .  Hopefully that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
For Each item As JProperty in results
    Dim rootName As String = item.Name
    Dim root As TreeNode = tvContent.Nodes.Add(rootName)
    dim sT as string = item.value("title")
    if sT isnot nothing then dim childnode as treenode = tvcontent.nodes(0).add(sT)
    dim s1 as string = item.value("001")
    if s1 isnot nothing then:         ' do whatever         :endif
    dim s2 as string = item.value("002") 
    if s2 isnot nothing then:         ' do whatever         : endif
    'etc
Next
```

using item.value("001") you specific that you want the value that belongs to the key "001" for the current 'item' in your results list

Here you specify a specific key or keys, the previous answer you loop through ALL possibilities